# Numpy where but keep original data that holds true

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

I have an array that I'm using np.where on. However, the output of the conditional statement just return the index of the true values.

Here's the statement I'm using:

```
data = np.where(data.OType.str.contains("YSOc"))
```

Input data

```
        Region     RAJ2000    DEJ2000                OType
0       LUP_III  242.588882 -38.644272                 Zero
1       LUP_III  242.588882 -39.302551                  two
2       LUP_III  242.588882 -39.377029                 star
3       LUP_III  242.595749 -38.762226                  one
4       LUP_III  242.602203 -39.317276                  two
        ...         ...        ...                  ...
582347  LUP_III  242.174133 -39.026955  YSOc_star+dust(MP1)
582348  LUP_III  242.178635 -39.104069  YSOc_star+dust(IR4)
582349  LUP_III  242.199524 -38.833614  YSOc_star+dust(IR4)
582350  LUP_III  242.205811 -39.094246  YSOc_star+dust(IR2)
582351  LUP_III  242.214279 -39.091789  YSOc_star+dust(IR2)
```

Output

```
(array([  4350,   5726,   6432,   9324,  13815,  14139,  18445,  29680,
        32350,  37842,  37956,  39458,  40384,  42086,  42241,  70026,
        87998,  95434,  95680, 100641, 140513, 144178, 158947, 161837,
       184541, 187837, 198310, 215526, 218879, 222999, 230776, 232013,
       233383, 235072, 251165, 259407, 267365, 268906, 269205, 286646,
       290633, 291358, 313746, 313779, 315215, 329447, 330986, 336783,
       336831, 339249, 341296, 348079, 351279, 351764, 353540, 356300,
       357192, 363877, 379226, 385232, 385635, 386531, 388968, 389570,
       397586, 400390, 402026, 436435, 438384, 439781, 443509, 447030,
       447881, 459637, 459906, 460051, 460722, 461185, 461459, 461556,
       461655, 461993, 465299, 465743, 466993, 467071, 468263, 469951,
       470610, 471196, 472743, 475490, 475665, 476385, 478243, 478549,
       478599, 478998, 484449, 485657, 486718, 486820, 486851, 487030,
       487446, 489547, 501403, 502071, 506799, 507159, 510826, 511213,
       512757, 513549, 514043, 514117, 514189, 514353, 514611, 514672,
       518171, 518276, 519617, 522213, 532190, 538127, 542022, 542202,
       542283, 542368, 547522, 547810, 548793, 552908, 554167, 557280,
       559775, 561043, 561541, 562073, 562375, 562401, 562634, 562699,
       562928, 562958, 564007, 564567, 567201, 568651, 570026, 573017,
       579175, 580137, 580332, 580402, 580473, 581081, 582273, 582274,
       582275, 582276, 582277, 582278, 582279, 582280, 582281, 582282,
       582283, 582284, 582285, 582286, 582287, 582288, 582289, 582290,
       582291, 582292, 582293, 582294, 582295, 582296, 582297, 582298,
       582299, 582300, 582301, 582302, 582303, 582304, 582305, 582306,
       582307, 582308, 582309, 582310, 582311, 582312, 582313, 582314,
       582315, 582316, 582317, 582318, 582319, 582320, 582321, 582322,
       582323, 582324, 582325, 582326, 582327, 582328, 582329, 582330,
       582331, 582332, 582333, 582334, 582335, 582336, 582337, 582338,
       582339, 582340, 582341, 582342, 582343, 582344, 582345, 582346,
       582347, 582348, 582349, 582350, 582351]),)
```

How do I make the output return the values from the original array that is returned from the statement rather than their indexes.

Comment: Are you using a Pandas DataFrame? If so, you don't even need `np.where`, just do `data[data.OType.str.contains("YSOc")]`.

Comment: This worked! I didn't even realise that I didn't need np.where

Comment: That use of `where` just returns a tuple, with an array of the indices where `data.OType.str.contains("YSOc")` is True.

Comment: @LewisCooper don't forget to accept one of the answers. That way, your question will be removed from the "unanswered" queue.

Answer (score 2):

What you're attempting to do is called [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

It looks like `data` is actually a Pandas DataFrame. If so, you don't even need `np.where`:

```py
data[data.OType.str.contains("YSOc")]
```

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for `np.where`, it points out that

> When only *condition* is provided, this function is a shorthand for [`np.asarray(condition).nonzero()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html#numpy.nonzero)

Looking at that documentation shows that the return type is a **tuple of arrays**. Notice the `,)` at the end of your output? The reason you got an `invalid key` error from the other answer was because you were actually trying to index with a tuple of arrays, instead of a plain array.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data[np.where(data.OType.str.contains("YSOc"))]`

This filters the original array by the indices given by the `where` function.

Comment: Doing this returns the error `(array([x,x,x,x,x.....])) is an invalid key`. Is that because it needs to be in the form of a list rather than an array? Or am I missing something

Comment: Just looked at it again. Like ddejohn said, do you have a pandas DataFrame? Then just use that. Works a bit different than a plain array.